# Change card color based on alertdialog option

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

I have a list of cards and each card has a long press function which when clicked, pops up an alert dialog. I would like the card to change color based on the option chosen in the alert dialog. My alert dialog has 3 options:
Completed (Card should change to color green),
In Progress ( Color orange),
Cancel (Color grey).

At first, when the screen loads, it should show list of cards each painted the color based on the value saved in the database. Then, when the user long presses a card and chooses an option from the alert dialog, the card's color should change based on the chosen option. Only that particular card's color should change.

I have read somewhere that this might be achievable using valuechangenotifier. So here's what I did so far:

First I created my changenotifier class like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorChanger with ChangeNotifier{

  Color _color = Colors.white;

  ColorChanger(this._color);

  getColor() => _color;

  setTheme (Color color) {
    _color = color;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Then I used it in my dart class. However, the color does not seem to change. What am I missing here?

```
class OrderItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final ord.OrderItem order;
  OrderItem(this.order);

  @override
  _OrderItemState createState() => _OrderItemState();
}

class _OrderItemState extends State<OrderItem> {
  var _expanded = false;
  var mycolor = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ColorChanger _color = Provider.of<ColorChanger>(context);
    var listProducts = widget.order.products;
    return Card(
      color: widget.order.orderStatus=='completed'
             ?Colors.lightGreen:widget.order.orderStatus=='inprogress'?
            Colors.orangeAccent:
             widget.order.orderStatus=='cancelled'?Colors.grey:mycolor,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: RichText(
              text: new TextSpan(
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  new TextSpan(
                      text: 'Order Number : ',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  new TextSpan(text: widget.order.uniqueOrderNumber),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(_expanded ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _expanded = !_expanded;
                });
              },
            ),
            onLongPress: toggleSelection,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void toggleSelection() {
     ColorChanger _color = Provider.of<ColorChanger>(context,listen:false);
     Widget completeOrder = FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Completed'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                       // setState(() {
                             _color.setTheme(Colors.lightGreen); 
                       // });
                        await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                            .updateOrder(widget.order,'completed');
                      } catch (error) {
                         
                      }
    });

    Widget startOrder = FlatButton(
                    child: Text('In progress'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                       // setState(() {
                          _color.setTheme(Colors.orangeAccent); 
                        //});
                        //Update Db to mark order in progress
                        await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                            .updateOrder(widget.order,'inprogress');
                      } catch (error) {
                         
                      }
    });

    Widget cancelOrder = FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                      //  setState(() {
                            _color.setTheme(Colors.grey); 
                      //  });
                        //Update Db to mark order as cancelled
                        await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                            .updateOrder(widget.order,'cancelled');
                      } catch (error) {
                         
                      }
    });
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Take Action'),
              content: Text('What do you want to do with the order?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                startOrder,
                completeOrder,
                cancelOrder
              ],
            ),
          );
      });
  }
}
```

**SECOND TRY based on Loren's answer.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorChanger with ChangeNotifier{

  Color color = Colors.white;

  setTheme (Color newColor) {
    color = newColor;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}


class OrderItem extends StatefulWidget {
      final ord.OrderItem order;
      OrderItem(this.order);
    
      @override
      _OrderItemState createState() => _OrderItemState();
    }
    
    class _OrderItemState extends State<OrderItem> {
      var _expanded = false;
      
      
      //Set the color based on what was last saved in the DB 
      void didChangeDependencies() async {
     var colorChanger = Provider.of<ColorChanger>(context, listen: false);
     if(widget.order.orderStatus=='completed')
        colorChanger.setTheme(Colors.lightGreen);
     else if(widget.order.orderStatus=='inprogress')
        colorChanger.setTheme(Colors.orangeAccent);
      else if(widget.order.orderStatus=='cancelled')
        colorChanger.setTheme(Colors.grey);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var listProducts = widget.order.products;
          return  Consumer<ColorChanger>(
       builder: (context, colorChanger, child) {
        return Card(
          color: widget.order.orderStatus=='completed'
                 ?Colors.lightGreen:widget.order.orderStatus=='inprogress'?
                Colors.orangeAccent:
                 widget.order.orderStatus=='cancelled'?Colors.grey:mycolor,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: RichText(
                  text: new TextSpan(
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      new TextSpan(
                          text: 'Order Number : ',
                          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      new TextSpan(text: widget.order.uniqueOrderNumber),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(_expanded ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _expanded = !_expanded;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                onLongPress: toggleSelection,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )};
      }
    
      void toggleSelection() {
         ColorChanger _color = Provider.of<ColorChanger>(context,listen:false);
         Widget completeOrder = FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Completed'),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          try {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                           // setState(() {
                                 _color.setTheme(Colors.lightGreen); 
                           // });
                            await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                                .updateOrder(widget.order,'completed');
                          } catch (error) {
                             
                          }
        });
    
        Widget startOrder = FlatButton(
                        child: Text('In progress'),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          try {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                           // setState(() {
                              _color.setTheme(Colors.orangeAccent); 
                            //});
                            //Update Db to mark order in progress
                            await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                                .updateOrder(widget.order,'inprogress');
                          } catch (error) {
                             
                          }
        });
    
        Widget cancelOrder = FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Cancel'),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          try {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                          //  setState(() {
                                _color.setTheme(Colors.grey); 
                          //  });
                            //Update Db to mark order as cancelled
                            await Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false)
                                .updateOrder(widget.order,'cancelled');
                          } catch (error) {
                             
                          }
        });
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Take Action'),
                  content: Text('What do you want to do with the order?'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    startOrder,
                    completeOrder,
                    cancelOrder
                  ],
                ),
              );
          });
      }
    }
```

When I do it this way, it changes the color of all the cards instead of just that one card. What am I doing wrong here?

Sharing **order.dart**

```
class OrderItem {
  final String id;
  final double amount;
  final int deliveryFee;
  final List<CartItem> products;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String deliveryMethod;
  final String uniqueOrderNumber;
  final String orderStatus; 
  final String userId;
  final String customMessage;
  final String customerName; 
  final String phoneNumber; 

  OrderItem( 
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.amount,
      @required this.products,
      @required this.dateTime,
      @required this.deliveryMethod,
      @required this.uniqueOrderNumber,
      @required this.isOrderComplete,
      this.orderStatus,
      @required this.customMessage,
      @required this.deliveryFee,
      this.customerName,
      this.phoneNumber,
      @required this.userId});
}

class Orders with ChangeNotifier {
  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  Orders(this.authToken, this.userId);

  List<OrderItem> _orders = [];
  List<OrderItem> get orders {
    return [..._orders];
  }
  Future<void> updateOrder(OrderItem order,String orderStatus) async {
final id = order.id;
final customerId = order.userId;
final url =
    'https://cv.firebaseio.com/orders/$customerId/$id.json?auth=$authToken';
     try {
         await http.patch(url,
           body: json.encode({
             'orderStatus':orderStatus
          }));
     } catch (error) {
     print(error);
   }
notifyListeners();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

So when trying to do this with Provider I kept getting errors that would have required me to keep bugging you for more and more code to try and replicate everything you have going on, and I didn't want to get into that.

So this solution may or may not be acceptable to you because it uses [GetX State Management](https://pub.dev/packages/get), but it works. In addition it doesn't require wrapping your whole app in provider widgets so dealing with scope etc...is a non issue.

Let's add a `statusColor` property to your `OrderItem` model. This is what will get changed.

```
 Color statusColor = Colors.white; // or whatever you you want the default color to be
```

Your updated `Orders` class that uses GetX instead of ChangeNotifier (again, not because Provider can't do this, but because I was dealing with too many errors and frankly GetX is easier in my opinion anyway)

```
class Orders extends GetxController {
  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  Orders(this.authToken, this.userId);

  List<OrderItem> orders = []; // back to what I said earlier about no point in getters and setters here

// temp function just to test this on my end
  void addOrder(OrderItem order) {
    orders.add(order);
    update();
  }

// this loops through the list to find the matching order number,
// then updates the color for just that order
  void updateOrderStatusColor({OrderItem updatedOrder, String status}) {
    for (final order in orders) {
      if (order.uniqueOrderNumber == updatedOrder.uniqueOrderNumber) {
        switch (status) {
          case 'completed':
            {
              order.statusColor = Colors.greenAccent;
            }
            break;
          case 'inprogress':
            {
              order.statusColor = Colors.orangeAccent;
            }
            break;
          case 'cancelled':
            {
              order.statusColor = Colors.grey;
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    update(); // equivelent of notifyListeners();
  }
  // ...the rest of your class
}
```

A few small changes to your card. `didChangeDependencies` can go away entirely.

```
// it seems like you had 2 classes with the same name, which is not recommended
class OrderItemCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final OrderItem order;

  OrderItemCard(this.order);

  @override
  _OrderItemCardState createState() => _OrderItemCardState();
}

class _OrderItemCardState extends State<OrderItemCard> {
  var _expanded = false;
  final controller = Get.find<Orders>(); // equivilent of Provider.of... finds the same instance without needing context

  void toggleSelection() {
    Widget completeOrder = TextButton(
        child: Text('Completed'),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);

            controller.updateOrderStatusColor(
                updatedOrder: widget.order, status: 'completed'); // calling new function here
          } catch (error) {}
        });

    Widget startOrder = FlatButton(
        child: Text('In progress'),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            controller.updateOrderStatusColor(
                updatedOrder: widget.order, status: 'inprogress');
          } catch (error) {}
        });

    Widget cancelOrder = FlatButton(
        child: Text('Cancel'),
        onPressed: () async {
          controller.updateOrderStatusColor(
              updatedOrder: widget.order, status: 'cancelled');
          try {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
          } catch (error) {}
        });

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Take Action'),
        content: Text('What do you want to do with the order?'),
        actions: <Widget>[startOrder, completeOrder, cancelOrder],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: widget.order.statusColor, // new color property added to your model
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: RichText(
              text: new TextSpan(
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  new TextSpan(
                      text: 'Order Number : ${widget.order.uniqueOrderNumber} ',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(_expanded ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _expanded = !_expanded;
                });
              },
            ),
            onLongPress: toggleSelection,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Not sure what you have going on in your UI but here's a quick demo of how it would work in GetX. It's a simple `ListView.builder` populated from the `orders` list from the GetX Class. The `GetBuilder<Orders>` widget rebuilds when `update()` is called. Also a simple button that adds a dummy item for demo purposes. I don't know how you're generating your unique order # but I'm just using the list index for this. Both inside a column within a scaffold on a demo page.

```
// Equivilent of Consumer but doesn't need context nor any provider widget above it
 GetBuilder<Orders>(
              builder: (controller) => Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.orders.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        OrderItemCard(controller.orders[index])),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final controller = Get.find<Orders>();
                final orderItem = OrderItem(
                  orderStatus: ' ',
                  uniqueOrderNumber: controller.orders.length
                      .toString(), // just a hack to generate a unique order # for demo
                );
                controller.addOrder(orderItem);
              },
              child: Text('Add Item'),
            )
```

Last thing is just initializing the GetX Controller. It can be done anywhere as long as its before you try and use it.

```
void main() {
  // initialing the GetX GetxController
  // not sure how you're generating the required auth and user id
  // but I'm just passing in empty strings for now
  Get.put(Orders('', ''));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

[image]

So if you're open to GetX here, you can leave Provider for any other `ChangeNotifier` classes you may have in place if you want. For this you would just need to replace any `Consumer<Orders>` with `GetBuilder<Order>` and then get rid of the `Provider<Orders>(create:...` widget entirely.

OLD ANSWER:

You're missing a couple things in order to be using Provider properly and get the color changing the way you want.

For starters, your `Card` needs to be wrapped in a `Consumer` widget that gets notified of changes and rebuilds its children. Inside the `Consumer`, you need to be using the color property of the `ChangeNotifier` class. It doesn't need to know or care about the `orderStatus` because you're already explicitly telling it to change color when you call the `setTheme` method.

```
Consumer<ColorChanger>(  // this is what rebuilds and changes the color
        builder: (context, colorChanger, child) {
      return Card(
        color: colorChanger.color, // colorChanger here is equivalent of declaring final colorChanger = Provider.of<ColorChanger>(context...
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: RichText(
                text: new TextSpan(
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    new TextSpan(
                        text: 'Order Number : ',
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    new TextSpan(text: widget.order.uniqueOrderNumber),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(_expanded ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _expanded = !_expanded;
                  });
                },
              ),
              onLongPress: toggleSelection,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

Next, [see this link](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html) as to why you're not gaining anything with using the private `_color` and public `getColor` in your `ChangeNotifier` class.

So lets simplify that a bit.

```
class ColorChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  Color color = Colors.white;

  ColorChanger(this.color);

  setTheme(Color newColor) {
    color = newColor;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now, whenever you call the `setTheme` function from your dialog, that card will change to whatever color you pass into it because the `Consumer` widget is notified, and will rebuild with the updated color value of the `ChangeNotifier` class.

Comment: please see my edited answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: I didn't realize you had multiple cards. How many cards do you have? Or does that change?

Comment: It changes depending on the number of orders. Each order resides in it's own card and each order is  associated with an order status. So I just want to change the order status for a particular card.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry perhaps I should have assumed there was more than one. Won't have time to look at this today but I'll check back in the next day or 2 and if you haven't found a solution I'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks loren. I will search more in these two days. I will reach out if I can't resolve it

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, I can try reproducing on my end. What is the `ord` in the `final ord.OrderItem order;`? If you're able to share your `Orders` class I imagine I'll have enough to do this on my end.

Comment: I have just shared it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't see that `updateOrder` function, thats really what I need as that appears to be when you need the colors to change is that correct?

Comment: Yes but all update order does is tht it stores the order status in the database. So for instance if you choose 'inprogress' from alert dialog, it will save that in the DB for that particular order. I'll share the code as well.

Comment: I have added the update function in the code.

Comment: You're right I didn't end up needing that sorry, I thought thats where you were trying to do it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the simplest way to the thing you want to achieve:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // define a list of colors:
  final colors = <Color>[
    Colors.white, // this is the inital color
    Colors.green,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.grey
  ];
  int index = 0;

  Future<int> showMyDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    // Since all Navigator.push(...) and showDialog(...) calls are futures
    // we can send values alongside them when we pop the context:
    // final value = await Navigator.push(...);
    // or
    // final value = await showDialog(...);
    // then we do a:
    // Navigator.pop(context, SOME_VALUE,);
    // the value variable will be assigned to the one we sent
    return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Take Action'),
        content: Text('What do you want to do with the order?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
              child: Text('Completed',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 1)),
          TextButton(
              child: Text('In progress',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  )),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 2)),
          TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  )),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 3)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          color: colors[index],
          child: Container(width: 50, height: 50),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Show dialog'),
            onPressed: () async {
              // call the showMyDialog function, it returns
              // a future int so we have to await it
              final int _index = await showMyDialog(context);
              
              // if the returned value (_index) is null we use
              // the old one value to avoid erros in the code
              setState(() => index = _index ?? index);
            }),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple workaround would be to declare a global color variable cardColor and assign it to the color property of the card. Then on the alertdialog, change the 'onChange'or 'onTap' property of the widget so that on tapping, the widget changes the value of the global variable cardColor to a different color. Don't forget to do the final step i.e. changing the value of the variable, inside setState()

Comment: How will this change the card color itself?

Comment: when you change the value of a variable (cardColor) in flutter inside a setState(), flutter changes all the UI elements visible that are dependent on that variable. Because color property of the card is set to variable cardColor, invoking setstate will change the active color of the card.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to achieve it by using  AwesomeDialog
https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog

```
AwesomeDialog(
            context: context,
            dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
            animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
            title: 'Dialog Title',
            desc: 'Dialog description here.............',
            btnCancelOnPress: () {},
            btnOkOnPress: () {},
            )..show();
```

Comment: How does this change the card color?

Comment: you can use btnCancelOnPress or btnOkOnPress to change the color of the card.